# Balanced Bracket Checker generates incorrect outputs

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, matching, brackets

I have created a function which uses Linked List to check whether an expression is balanced or not. But the function **'Bracket Balancing'** always gives 'unbalanced' as the output no matter what the input is.

**NOTE: A balanced expression has no. of opening brackets '(' equal to no. of closing brackets ')'**

**CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LL{
    char data;
    struct LL *next;
};

int isEmpty(struct LL *top){
    if (top == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct LL *top){
    struct LL *n = malloc(sizeof(struct LL *));
    if (n == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

struct LL *push(struct LL *top, char x){
    if (isFull(top)){
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    }
    else{
        struct LL *n = malloc(sizeof(struct LL));
        n->data = x;
        n->next = top;
        top = n;
    }
    return top;
}

struct LL *pop(struct LL *top){
    if (isEmpty(top)){
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
    }
    else{
        struct LL *n = malloc(sizeof(struct LL));
        n = top;
        top = top->next;
        free(n);
    }
    return top;
}

int BracketBalancing(char *exp){
    struct LL *top = malloc(sizeof(struct LL));
    top->next = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (exp[i] == '('){
            push(top, exp[i]);
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ')'){
            if (isEmpty(top)){
                return 0;
            }
            pop(top);
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(top)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int n;
    char *expression = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter the length of the expression for Bracket Balancing\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the expression for Bracket Balancing\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%c ", &expression[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    if (BracketBalancing(expression)){
        printf("The expression is balanced\n");
    }
    else if (!BracketBalancing(expression)){
        printf("This expression is unbalanced\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

**Input:**

```
Enter the length of the expression for Bracket Balancing 
4
Enter the expression for Bracket Balancing
1+()
```

**Output:**

```
This expression is unbalanced
```

In the above example, despite the expression being balanced my code generates incorrect output. Please correct my code.

Comment: The `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates *one byte* of memory so you'll get buffer overflow. Move it *after* the `n` input, as `char *expression = malloc(n + 1);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're Right, but the output generated is still incorrect

Comment: I pointed out the first thing I saw. if I were to write this program, I would remove everthing and focus on the input. Input the expression you want to check, and print that expression back to the user. Then try an expression that is longer than you promised, and so on. Only when that works "properly" would I move on the next step.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you initialize your list:

```
struct LL *top = malloc(sizeof(struct LL));
top->next = NULL;
```

And this is `isEmpty()`:

```
int isEmpty(struct LL *top)
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**But**: `top` starts with a value != NULL, so `isEmtpy()` will not return 1, although our list should be empty in the beginning.

Your implementation of `push()` should work fine when you pass NULL, so you can just initialize `struct LL *top = NULL;` instead of creating the first element rightaway.

there other bugs in your code, e.g.:

- in `pop()` you do

  ```
    struct LL *n = malloc(sizeof(struct LL));
    n = top;
  ```

thus, the result of `malloc()` is directly overwritten() in the next line

- in `isFull()` you produce a memory leak as you call `malloc()` and never use or `free()` the buffer returned. That function doesn't make sense anyway, just check the result of `malloc()`s where your really want to *use* the buffer returned.

** Edit **

What I haven't seen before, you also never use the return value of `push()` and `pop()` so the new top determined by these function is lost. Replace `push(top, ...);` by `top = push(top,...);` and `pop(top);` by `top = pop(top);`

Comment: How can I initialize my list with a null value in `top`? I tried this :  `top->data = NULL`. It generates the error: `warning: assignment to 'char' from 'void *' makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: see my edit ...

Comment: On further testing, I found out, that now my code gives all expressions as "balanced" even if they are not. I removed all the bugs in my code as you specified but that still has not rectified the problem.

Comment: The corrected version of the function :                                                                           
 `int ParenthesisMatching(char *exp)
  {
    struct LL *top = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(')
        {
            push(top, exp[i]);
        }
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            if (isEmpty(top))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            pop(top);
        }
    }
    if (isEmpty(top))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}`

Comment: See the next edit. But maybe you could ask yourself if you could have found it by yourself. The learning effect would be higher and I guess that's what you're doing it for :-)

Comment: It did not work :-(    (You can try testing the code, it still gives incorrect outputs). Maybe there are some logical errors in my code that I have not yet found. But I appreciate the efforts you put in to correct my code. :-)